# Serilog stops writing to file

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, .net-4.8

I'm using Serilog to log Errors in my WebApi with the following configuration.

```
private static readonly string LogFileName = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/Logs/Service.log");

    private static void ConfigureLogging(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.File(LogFileName != null ? LogFileName : "C:/Temp/Logs/Service.log",
                shared: true,
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day);
        // configure global logger for logging in owin middleware
        Log.Logger = loggerConfig.CreateLogger();
        builder.Register(_ => Log.Logger).As<ILogger>();  }`
```

With Appsettings

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Warning" />
</appSettings>
```

The problem is, it only logs once. The Service is still alive, I can send more Successful requests.
And I also see the requests/errors logged in console. But it doesnt add up in logfile.

BUT if I edit the WebConfig - change from Warning to Verbose then back to Warning, so no real changes - it logs again.

Comment: You need to flush the logger after each write.  The data is moved from the logger to a file when the buffer is full.  You probably have data in the buffer and didn't close the logger when application ended and didn't get all the messages saved to the file.

Comment: Is it `flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)` that you mean? Because that doesnt fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe ... https://gist.github.com/benfoster/1240d93cc18a0742969c8bf12254ed2c

Comment: Thank you for this hint, I also stumbled upon this post where the reason was missing dispose

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260308/only-first-logging-shows-unless-forcefully-disposing

Answer (score 0):

For Debugging and diagnostic use this selflog which might show you the extact error or problem your application is facing. Check this here https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics